# Unable to catch Network Error when sending request using Inertia + Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, inertiajs

While sending a `this.$inertia.patch` request I'm unable to catch a Network Error. I'm turning off the backend server to emulate a lost connection. The console shows: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error`.

I've tried Inertia's `onError`, tried adding a `.catch` after the request as well as a separate `try...catch` and used the Vue 2's

```
errorCaptured: function(err) {
   console.log('Caught error', err.message)
},
```

I can give more details if needed.

So basically trying to catch `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

**Edit: I moved to using `onFinish` along with `onSuccess` and `onStart`, but finally used `axios`**

Answer (score 0):

Use `onStart` along with `onSuccess` and `onFinish`:

- In the case of a network error, `onFinish` will trigger *without* `onSuccess`.
- In the case of a server error `onError` will trigger *with* `onFinish`